# The command `gcloud container clusters get-credentials ` will not create a kubeconfig

Tags: gcloud, kubectl

When I type `gcloud container clusters get-credentials`, I get response `entry generated for ***.`. and it looks like it is generated, but when I hit `kubectl config view`, there is nothing.

[Reference of `gcloud container clusters get-credentials`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials) says,

> gcloud container clusters get-credentials **updates** a kubeconfig file with appropriate credentials and endpoint information to point kubectl at a specific cluster in Google Kubernetes Engine.

So I thought the problem was that `~/.kube/config` did not exist, but creating an empty file did not change it.

[image: The command gcloud container clusters get-credentials will not create a kubeconfig.]

Comment: Please try the `gcloud container get-credentials` with `--verbosity=debug`. I wonder whether `gcloud` is unable (not permitted) to write to `${HOME}` perhaps `${HOME}/.kube`. perhaps check `ls -la` on both for ownership?

Comment: Perhaps and/or with `--log-http` to confirm that the underlying calls are succeeding (though I suspect they are) and it's a local issue

Comment: I think `kubectl config view` is defaulting to null values because it's unable to find `~/.kube/config`

Comment: It was due to a rudimentary mistake regarding the WSL, Sorry... The verbosity flag helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DazWilkin in the comments for suggesting running the command with the `--verbosity=debug` flag, which then outputted where it was writing the file.

The reason was that the `PATH` of WSL included the `PATH` of the Windows side by default, so it was calling the `gcloud` on Windows (installed by scoop).
I solved the problem by excluding the `PATH` of Windows, referring to [this gists](https://gist.github.com/ilbunilcho/4280bd55a10cefef75e74986b6bff936).